# Firebase Google Auth not working on Cordova Android

Tags: android, firebase, cordova, firebase-authentication

I have some issue with Firebase Google Login, which is not working on Android with Cordova (it was working perfectly on Web).  I have followed these instructions: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/cordova

I think the problem comes from firebase's dynamic link or the cordova-plugin-universal-link. Please help me i'm just a beginner in Firebase and Cordova. Thank you very much.

Here is my Dynamics link on firebase and my code:

My Dynamic link:

[My Dynamic link image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KEf5P.png)

My code on config.xml:

```
 <universal-links>
    <host name="https://rentlz.page.link/index" scheme="https" />
    <host name="https://project-rental-5593e.firebaseapp.com/" scheme="https">
        <path url="/__/auth/callback"/>
    </host>
</universal-links>
<preference name="AndroidLaunchMode" value="singleInstance" />
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="29" />
```

My javascript src:

```
<script src=" js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="./bundle.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/firebase/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/firebase/firebase-analytics.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/node_modules/firebase/firebase-auth.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="src/firebase.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/auth.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/database.js"></script>
```

My auth.js code:

```
$(document).on("vclick", "#login", SignIn);
$(document).on("vclick", "#logout", SignOut);
/**
 * Handles the sign in button press.
 */
function SignIn() {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider).then(function() {
        return firebase.auth().getRedirectResult();
    }).then(function(result) {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token.
        // You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
        // ...

    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
    });

    firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
        if (result.credential) {
            // This gives you a Google Access Token.
            // You can use it to access the Google API.
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            // The signed-in user info.
            var user = result.user;
            // ...

        }
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
    });


}

function SignOut() {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
        // Sign-out successful.
    }).catch(function(error) {
        // An error happened.
    });
}

function initApp() {
    // Listening for auth state changes.
    // [START authstatelistener]
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            console.log(user.photoURL)
                // User is signed in.
            var displayName = user.displayName;
            var photoURL = user.photoURL;
            var uid = user.uid;
            var providerData = user.providerData;
            $("#login").hide();
            $("#logout").show();
            document.getElementById("userimg").setAttribute("src", photoURL);
            document.getElementById("username").innerHTML = displayName;
            $("#card").show();
            $("#post-contain").show();
            $("#login-contain").hide();
        } else {
            // User is signed out.
            $("#login").show();
            $("#card").hide();
            $("#logout").hide();
            $("#post-contain").hide();
            $("#login-contain").show();


        }

    });
    // [END authstatelistener]

}
window.onload = function() {
    initApp();
};
```